# Unable to connect to MongoDB from a Django containorized app

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm writing an application with django and I want to use mongoDB as my database. But I am unable to connect to it. The error I get is:

```
ConnectionFailure: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

My settings for Connection are:

```
import mongoengine
_MONGODB_USER = 'root'
_MONGODB_PASSWD = '12345'
_MONGODB_HOST = '192.168.8.101'
_MONGODB_NAME = 'admin'
_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST = \
    'mongodb://%s:%s@%s/%s' \
    % (_MONGODB_USER, _MONGODB_PASSWD, _MONGODB_HOST, _MONGODB_NAME)

mongoengine.connect(_MONGODB_NAME, host=_MONGODB_DATABASE_HOST)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Some questions:

You mentioned Django containerized app in question. Do you mean a Docker container running you Django app?
What about your MongoDB, is it containerized?
What are your docker run commands?

Comment: @abilinx Yes, that means a docker container running the app and mongodb is running outside. But never mind, I figured it out myself. Thanks for your reply though.